# How do I make a CSS drop shadow responsive?

Tags: css, svg

I have the following drop-shadow applied to an SVG image. The problem with this is that when the site is scaled down to a lower res the shadow gets further and further away from  the image. The drop-shadow filter does not allow you to use percentages.

```
#turqLogo img
{

 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 4%;
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(.5em 0px 0px black); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 filter: drop-shadow(.5em 0px 0px black);
}
```

Anyone have a trick to make the shadow stay in the same position as the site is being viewed at different resolutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 1vw instead of .5em.

1vw = 1% of viewport width.

```
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1vw 0px 0px black); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 filter: drop-shadow(1vw 0px 0px black);
```

Example, the svg drop shadow keeps it's distance when scaled:

[image: svg drop shadow]

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the shadow depending by the width of the screen with this:

```
@media (min-width: 300px) { //set there your width

 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 4%;
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(.5em 0px 0px black); /* new style here */
 filter: drop-shadow(.5em 0px 0px black);  /* new style here */

 }
```

Just add in in the style sheet and you will see that once the page reach that min-width it will reapply the  style to your component ;)

Comment: This works too, but replacing em with vw (as mentioned above) seems to be a simpler more effective solution.

Comment: This will work if you make a media query for each standard resolution and adjust the shadow em/px for each. If it is between two resolutions, the shadow will begin to drift.